# Why is my component that receives props not working when I destructure out the properties, but when I use props.key it's working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

**The Problem**

I have an application that uses this React Redux Boilerplate: https://github.com/flexdinesh/react-redux-boilerplate

I created a new page that is connected to the injected reducer + saga. 
I receive following props: `posts`, `loading`, `error`, `loadPosts` and `match`

When I use these directly the app is working as expected. But as soon as I start to destructure the props, the app is behaving unexpectedly.

Especially with the `match` props.

**When I do it like this:**

```
const SubforumPage = (props) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        const { id: subId } = props.match.params;
        console.log('props: ', subId);
      }, []);
    // .... other code
    }
```

**No problem everything works.**

**But when I do it like this:**

```
const SubforumPage = ({match}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { id: subId } = match.params;
    console.log('props: ', subId);
  }, []);
// .... other code
}
```

## `match` suddenly gets undefined!

I have really no clue what so ever why this is happening. It's the first time that I see an error like this.

This specific page is set up like this in the routing file:

`<Route path="/sub/:id" component={SubforumPage} />`

And it's clearly working when using `(props)` in the function arguments but not with `({match})`

Why is this? Can please someone help me out here.

## What have I tried?

- I continuesly started destructuring one prop after another. At first this approach works and it's still not undefined but when I get to some props, it's different which ones, it will stop working.

I think it has to do something with how I use my `useEffect()` hook? 
I pass an empty array so it does just run when mounting. It seems like when I refresh the page, the posts are cleared out but the useEffect doesn't run anymore, so the new posts doesn't get fetched. Because hen also the `console.log` inside the `useEffect` hook is <s>undefined</s> doesn't even run. But for example the `loading` prop in `console.log` outside of useEffect is indeed not `undefined`
(But that still does not explain why it's working with `(props)` as argument).

**Am I just using `useEffect` wrong?**

Many thanks

Comment: Interesting! For testing, can you remove that `[]` dependency array from your `useEffect` and see what happens?

Comment: Then it's still not working. But I might have found the error. Is it possible that `useEffect` is async and it still tries to render the component. Because what I return is this `return <PostsGroup posts={posts} />` and then it says that `posts` is not defined. 
I think now that I think it tries to pass in the `posts` but it's not yet available because of the useEffect beein async and has to wait for response from server. 
Tested it like this `return <PostsGroup posts={posts || [] } />` and now it seems to work correctly. 
Oh man wall of text for nothing :P
Thx for trying though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ok guys that was completely my fault. Guess I'm too tired :D. Here is what caused the problem:*

I fetch my post in the `useEffect` hook. I also render a component where I pass in the `posts`. But the posts are not available because the component has to wait for the data to come in. So I completely forgot that I have to wait for the data.

**Before:**

`return <PostsGroup posts={posts} />;`

**After: (correct)**

`return <PostsGroup posts={posts || []} />;`

I had a check in place looking like this:

`if (loading) return <CircularProgress />;`

(before the other return). But it doesn't matter because loading is false when the component initially renders. 
So I also set the initial value from `loading` to `true` (in my initialState of the reducer). So I have now two checks in place.

Sorry guys. So stupid.